# Mule deployment fails- Cannot assign requested address

Tags: https, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, mule-esb

I have developed an api which consumes google api's that use oauth 2.0. The api is successfully deployed in local with following configuration: 1. https on port 8443. 2. redirection url : https://localhost:8082/callback 3. local authorization url : https://localhost:8082/login

having the same configuration on dev server yet it is failing to deploy. (replacing localhost with dev server hostname and port remains the same)

```
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "start" on object: org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequesterConfig@397b430b
 at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:242) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:134) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:141) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:70) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:62) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:317) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:139) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 ... 56 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChannelAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:131) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:88) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:239) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:219) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:210) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.33.jar:2.3.33]
 at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyServer.start(GrizzlyServer.java:41) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListenerConfig.start(DefaultHttpListenerConfig.java:274) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpListenerConfigBuilder.build(HttpListenerConfigBuilder.java:68) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.module.http.api.listener.HttpListenerBuilder.resolveListenerConfig(HttpListenerBuilder.java:276) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.module.http.api.listener.HttpListenerBuilder.build(HttpListenerBuilder.java:195) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.module.oauth2.internal.authorizationcode.AuthorizationRequestHandler.init(AuthorizationRequestHandler.java:99) ~[mule-module-oauth-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.module.oauth2.internal.authorizationcode.DefaultAuthorizationCodeGrantType.start(DefaultAuthorizationCodeGrantType.java:246) ~[mule-module-oauth-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequesterConfig.start(DefaultHttpRequesterConfig.java:348) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor594.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:230) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:134) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:141) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:70) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:62) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:317) ~[mule-core-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:139) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.6.jar:3.8.6]
 ... 56 more
```

`<http:request-config name="HTTP-GsuiteApi-Request-Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="www.googleapis.com" port="443" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" >
         <oauth2:authorization-code-grant-type clientId="${client_id}" clientSecret="${client_secret}" redirectionUrl="https://devserverurl:8082/callback" tlsContext-ref="TLS_Context">
             <oauth2:authorization-request authorizationUrl="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth" localAuthorizationUrl="https://devserverurl:8082/login" scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user"/>
             <oauth2:token-request tokenUrl="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token">
                 <oauth2:token-response accessToken="#[json:access_token]"/>
             </oauth2:token-request>
         </oauth2:authorization-code-grant-type>
 </http:request-config>`

Comment: The port you are using may be already in use.Can you please try changing it to some other value?Let me know if that works..

Comment: I tried changing the port @M

Answer (score 0):

We have been seeing the same error. We were trying to configure two separate listeners on the same host for two different URL's. Our original listener was configured with 0.0.0.0 which was working and binding to any address. Changing this to a domain name caused us to see the same error you were getting.

We were able to fix this by adding an entry to the windows host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) mapping the domain name to the server IP Address or 127.0.0.1

Sorry a little late with the reply, but hopefully this helps someone.